# tampermonkey script to extension (io is not defined)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, socket.io

I always used tampermonkey to install my scipt and it worked perfectly.

Now to make it easier for my clients, i wanted to make a chrome extension.

In my tampermonkey script i was able to add

```
// @require      https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.4/socket.io.min.js
```

and use above:

```
var socket = io.connect('somewhere');
```

to use it in my extension i added a .jsonfile - the important part:

```
"content_scripts": [
        {
            "js": [ "js/jquery.js", "js/content.js", "js/socket.io.min.js" ],
            "matches": [ "http://agar.io/", "http://agar.io/?", "http://agar.io/index.html", "https://agar.io/", "https://agar.io/?" ],
            "run_at": "document_start"
        }
    ],
```

and downloaded the socket.io.min.js from https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/socket.io/1.4.4/socket.io.min.js
 and included it in the folder js/ ....

after i installed the extension, it says in the console: io is not defined

Comment: Swap the order of `content.js` and `socket.io.min.js`....

Comment: @RobW didn't help :(

Comment: Don't forget to reload the extension via chrome://extensions after editing the manifest file.

Comment: @RobW reinstalled...didn't helped